# Needed helpful hand with a bit complicated query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table 'Tasks' with the following structure

```
[TaskId],[CompanyId], [Year], [Month], [Value]
220,1,2018,1,50553.32
220,2,2018,2,222038.12
```

and another table where users have permissions to particular companies in table named 'UsersCopmpanies'

```
[UserId], [CompanyId]
1,1
```

and the thing is task no. 220 was moved between companies. In January task belonged to copmanyId=1 and than in February this task belonged to copmanyId = 2.

According to the table 'UsersCopmpanies' user does not have permision to compnayid = 2.

What I need to do is to get both rows from table 'Tasks' expect field Value, because user does not have persmission.
Expected result should be:

```
[TaskId], [CompanyId], [Year], [Month],[Value]
220,1,2018,1,50553.32
220,2,2018,2,(NULL or somenthing else for.example string 'lack of permission')
```

Comment: Have you considered keeping a history table, so that a suer can still access some information that may be related to a them previously? That doesn't mean they would be able to access the current data, but it would mean that could still see things that are no longer assigned in the state they were left in.

Comment: Aside: Using classified data types in your question leaves us guessing, but having a column with multiple data types, e.g. either `money` or `varchar(42)` depending on a value in another table, doesn't tend to go well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this query using LEFT JOIN can be work at you expected :

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTasks  
(TaskId   int,  
   CompanyId      int,
   YearCol varchar(50),
   MonthCol varchar(50),
   SomeValue varchar(50)
  );  
GO  

INSERT INTO #MyTasks 
SELECT 220,1,2018,1,50553.32
UNION
SELECT 220,2,2018,2,222038.12

CREATE TABLE #MyUsersCopmpanies
(UserId   int PRIMARY KEY,  
   CompanyId      varchar(50) 
  );  
GO  



INSERT INTO #MyUsersCopmpanies 
SELECT 1,1


DECLARE  @MyUserParam INT = 1;

SELECT #MyTasks.TaskId, #MyTasks.CompanyId, #MyTasks.YearCol, #MyTasks.MonthCol, 
    CASE WHEN #MyUsersCopmpanies.UserId IS NOT NULL THEN  #MyTasks.SomeValue ELSE 'lack of permission' END AS 'ValueTaskByPermissions'
FROM #MyTasks 
LEFT JOIN #MyUsersCopmpanies ON #MyUsersCopmpanies.CompanyId = #MyTasks.CompanyId AND #MyUsersCopmpanies.UserId = @MyUserParam;


DROP TABLE  #MyTasks

DROP TABLE  #MyUsersCopmpanies
```

RESULT :

```
TaskId  CompanyId   YearCol MonthCol    ValueTaskByPermissions
220             1      2018        1    50553.32
220             2      2018        2    lack of permission
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `left join`:

```
select t.TaskId, t.CompanyId, t.Year, t.Month, 
       (case when uc.CompanyId is not null then Value end) as Value
from tasks t left join
     UsersCompanies uc
     on uc.CompanyId = t.CompanyId and uc.UserId = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Some code :

```
SELECT t.taskid,t.companyid,t.year,t.month, 
       (CASE WHEN u.companyid IS NOT NULL THEN t.value ELSE "lack of permission" end) AS ValueData 
FROM `x_task` t LEFT JOIN x_userscopmpanies u ON u.companyid = t.companyid
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and put the code in { } mark in toolbar.

Comment: As its dependent permission on if user have the company then it will show the value if not then not, So no need to check the user id,